# \Xendlemmaseparator from eledmac produces "undefined control sequence". What is wrong?

Tags: texlive, eledmac

as per title: everything else I do with the `eledmac` package works fine. The manual says that `\lemmaseparator` can be used to change the separator used in footnotes, and `\Xendlemmaseparator` accordingly for endnotes. I have the critical notes of my document in endnotes, and as a default `eledmac` does not have a lemma separator in this case. So, I would like to apply `\Xendlemmaseparator`, but my LaTeX throws a "undefined control sequence".

Did I miss something?

This is the version of LaTeX installed on my machine:

```
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)
```

This is how the command should be used according to the manual:

```
\Xendlemmaseparator[A]{\rbracked}
```

Where `[A]` is the corresponding series of the endnotes.

Here is some latex code that reproduces the error (for me):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{bookman}
    \usepackage[parapparatus]{eledmac}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \author{Ingo Kieslich}
    \title{test}
    \date{}
    \begin{document}      
    \lineation{page}
    \beginnumbering 
    \pstart 
This is a \edtext{test}{\Aendnote{the rest}} of swift  testiness. 
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \Xendlemmaseparator[A]{\rbracket}
    \doendnotes{A}
    \end{document}
```

Thanks for any hints you might be able to give me!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with TeX Live 2014, but not with TeX Live 2015. What's your version of `eledmac`? I have `eledmac 2015/06/21 v1.24.1`

Comment: The log file says: Package: eledmac 2014/10/20 v1.13.4 LaTeX port of EDMAC. So, I probably should update it. Could you give me a hint as to how I can do that?

Comment: Problem solved. I updated the eledmac package to its latest version and can now use the '\Xendlemmaseparator' command. You can download the package from: [http://www.ctan.org/] and the following page explains how to update packages of texlive on Ubuntu: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX ]. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction, @egreg.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved with a software update.